# Prevent access to a partition on Windows

Tags: windows, partitioning, security, accessibility

I would like to have two Windows installations on two physically separate drives on the same computer and dual boot them. But I would like to restrict each installation to access the other's partition. By access I mean protect from users, services, malware etc. Is there a secure way to achieve it? (Without VMs if possible.)

Comment: The best you can do is hide a drive letter with a group policy.  That’s easily bypassed by using a different drive letter

Comment: If you plan to boot Linux & Windows, make the Linux partition ext4 (default in most distros). Windows needs a tool such as DiskGenius to access ext4, though with such a tool, it can. The only *sure* way to have two completely separate OS's is to put them on two removable disks.

Answer (score 2):

This is made much simpler by the fact that you have two separate physical drives. One way to do this would be to enable bitlocker on each drive. Neither Windows OC would be able to access the others encrypted drive. Another option that would prevent access to the files would be to encrypt the entire thing with the built in EFS encryption. This is very simple through the command line.

Via the command line as an administrator run `cipher /e /s:C:/` This will encrypt the entire boot drive, and all of the files. Do it once from each Windows install. Users would still be able to access the partitions and see the names of the files, but would not be able to open them. You are encrypting the files, not the drive or the folders.

Turning on Bitlocker would encrypt the drive, preventing users from seeing anything about it. Number of files, names of files, anything at all would be inaccessible.